# android google maps camera update,zoom

Tags: android, google-maps, zooming

Hi I have an issue with my Google maps camera and zoom. Basically I have a class where I have markers and info windows as well as the map itself. In another activity I have another class and an option of view on map, but when I click on the view on map option the camera, zoom does not updates & zooms the map on the location that I have set it to. Any advice guys ? Thanks.

Here is my code where i set the map class to run when the option is selected as well as to update the camera and zoom to the specific location. What I need is to update the camera and zoom to the LOCATION_bar when the option is selected, but what happens is that just the map is opening without zooming or focusing the location_bar.

```
  public class barzoomin extends Activity {
GoogleMap gMap;
private final LatLng LOCATION_bar=new LatLng(x , y);


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent intentvbar = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), THEMAP.class);
    startActivity(intentbar);
    gMap=((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    gMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LOCATION_bar,18);
    gMap.animateCamera(update);

}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with another API key. I had the same problem and it solved it!